# How to hide a JFrame when a JDialog class is open

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jdialog

I am tring to Hide a JFrame when a JDialog box opened, please how doi do this usuing the addActionListener();

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a JDialog you should be specifying the JFrame as the owner of the dialog, then you can use the `getOwner()` method of the dialog to get the frame reference at any time.

In you JDialog you should be able to use a `WindowListener`.

1. In the `windowOpened` event you hide the frame
2. in the `windowClosed` event you show the frame.