# Java - How to close a window on open of a dialog

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

i created a dialog class that opens when a JLabel is clicked but i want the main window to close when the label is clicked and a more bigger issue is that the label is in a class that extends a JPanel now if the label is clicked the panel goes as in setVisible(false), do you get what i mean, but when i tried to use polymorphism in the panel class to obtain both the main window class and the dialog it proved successful but when the label is clicked an new similar main 
wnidow pops up and immediately disappears. ie it duplicates the main window, i know that this problem might look like a chalenge because there are no codes, the file is too complicated but i kmow there is a pro out there who can get a picture of what this code is and help me, thank you

Comment: Show some code here too so we can help

Comment: I answered your question in this posting (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22334749/how-to-hide-a-jframe-when-a-jdialog-class-is-open) and you didn't appreciated the help, so I won't bother helping this time.

Comment: sorry camickr, i couldnt give a thumb up because i dpnt have enoghh privilage to do so but i can accept your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "an new similar main wnidow pops up and immediately disappears. ie it duplicates the main window, " -

Seeing how your `JPanel` is a separate class, it seems to me like you have a referencing issue. I bet what you did was create a `new MainWindow` so that you could reference it. Like

```
mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
    window.dispose();
}
```

That would definitely explain the the issue. There are a few ways to deal with this. I'm going to give you the rookie way, since you still seem like a rook :D You'll probably learn more proper ways as your learning gets deeper. So you can do something like below, where you pass the *reference* of the `MainWindow` to the `JPanel` class, instead of creating a `new MainWindow`

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    private MainWindow window;

    public MyPanel(final MainWindow window) {
        this.window = window;
        JLabel label = new Label();
        label.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                window.setVisible(false); // or dispose
            }
        });
    } 
}
```

When you instantiate the `MyPanel`, pass the reference of the `MainWindow` to the `MyPanel`, like `MyPanel panel = new MyPanel(MainWindow.this);`

Comment: you are the pro, thatks for showing this rookie how